# Library not loaded (Dyld Message). Only on 32bits devices

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-custom-framework

I've encountered a problem on iPhone 5C. My application crashes directly on the launch with this message :

```
Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/SharedFitback.framework/SharedFitback
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5646575-C0E6-462C-8A4A-F445C52FDE91/Patient.app/Patient
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 390.7
```

I tried with an iPhone 5S, 6 et 6S and it works, but the problem appear when I try to run it on 4S, 5 and 5C devices.

Based on this tests, I imagine that the issue is linked to the architecture.

I knew this kind of issue, but never had it on just few models.

--

**Here is my configuration on my *SharedFitback.plist***

- *Architectures*
  [image: Custom Library plist valid architectures - Dyld Message: Library not loaded]
- *Linking*
  [image: Custom Library plist linking - Dyld Message: Library not loaded]

--

**Here is my configuration on my *Patient.app* - General section**

[image: Custom framework - Dyld Message: Library not loaded]

**It sounds like SharedFitback is only compatible for 64bits devices**.

Is anyone have an idea about this issue ?

Comment: iPhone 4S, 5 and 5C - are 32 bit devices. Looks like SharedFitback.framework 64 bit only framework

Comment: Yes, I did the same conclusion, but how to build SharedFitback for 32/64bits ?